# Integrating PowerBI with the ServiceNow

Tags: powerbi, servicenow

I want to create a dashboard which should connect to serviceNow application, fetch data and create a dashboard.

Can somebody please tell me how to achieve it.

Do we need ServiceNow API's and also admin access to go ahead or is it possible without that also.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53496481/integrate-servicenow-to-powerbi

Comment: But there is no solution provided for this question.

Comment: That doesn't mean you should ask an identical question.

Comment: But I have the same requirement. So, what should I do.

Comment: The same as the original poster of that question - wait for an answer... or better still, read [ask] and ask a better, more specific question, which shows some research, and asks for help tackling a specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

Connecting a BI tool directly to a production ServiceNow instance might significantly affect its performance.

For bigger ServiceNow instances with a lot of data, this approach won't work at all because it will take ages to download the data for your report.

There is the best practice of creating a dedicated reporting database containing a copy of the data. Either on-premise DB or an Azure one. And then connecting Power BI to this traditional database. You won't be impacting ServiceNow and the reports will be way faster.

Please use SnowMirror (https://www.snow-mirror.com/) or similar tools to create such a reporting database.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try the canned [ServiceNow content pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-connect-to-servicenow). That should take 10 minutes to have a dashboard running with your data. It isn’t very customizable except by doing Q&A to create and pin new visuals. But it is easy.

Unfortunately this approach does not work for many ServiceNow tenants because single sign-on is enabled. As the link above states:

> When prompted, enter your ServiceNow Basic credentials. Note single sign on is not supported today

I would recommend you vote [here](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200/suggestions/8106117) for a proper ServiceNow connector in Power BI Desktop.

If you have Power Query skills you could investigate calling [REST API](https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/catlist/c_GettingStartedWithREST-Container?v=kingston)s yourself to import ServiceNow data. Unfortunately I don’t know of a code sample anyone has published for this.

Comment: Failed to update data source credentials: The credentials provided for the ServiceNow source are invalid. (Source at https://bp.service-now.com/.)

Comment: I am getting this error when I try connecting PowerBI with service now Incidents

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I have updated my answer. We have successfully used the content pack with a client of mine but they did not have single sign-on enabled like your tenant does. To be honest they did not find the content pack super helpful and decided to add ServiceNow tables to their data warehouse via SSIS packages to extract data. Then Power BI just imports those tables.